# add table_id to the result from multiple tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is how I structured the data in BigQuery database.

```
test
  -> sales
    -> monthly-2015
    -> monthly-2016
    -> ...
```

I want to combine the data of all tables **with the table name** , `monthly-*`, and below is how I wrote the sql from examples I found. 
Running this sql leads an error like following `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`. How could I fix it to error?

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
  SELECT
    table_id
  FROM
    `test.sales.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
  WHERE
    table_id LIKE 'monthly-%')
FROM
  `test.sales.monthly*`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to combine the data of all tables with the table name , `monthly-*`

Try below

```
SELECT *, 'monthly_' || _TABLE_SUFFIX as table_name 
FROM `test.sales.monthly_*`
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I figure my question wasn't clear. I want to have the table name which the data is listed, so in this case, all the table data with the table name like ```monthly-2015``` etc.